# How to pass a variable into a SQL query

Tags: java, mysql, variables

I was passing a String from one scene to another, both are with different controllers in JavaFX and using that string to excute a sql statement but gets the error of 'check the manual corresponding to maria DB server'. I will put my relevent codes down. Any help would be appreciated.
menu.fxml ----> MenuController.java AND orderList.fxml ----> OrderListController.java

```
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("orderList.fxml"));
                Parent root = loader.load();
                OrderListController orderListController = loader.getController();
                orderListController.transferMessage(orderRefNo);
                Stage orderListStage = new Stage();
                orderListStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
                orderListStage.show();
```

```
public class OrderListController implements Initializable {

    private String orderRefNo;
    public void transferMessage(String message){
        orderRefNo = message;
    }

    public OrderListController() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        try {
            //ResultSet resultSet = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+orderRefNo+"");
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ?");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, orderRefNo);
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()){
                observableList.add(new orderListTableModel(resultSet.getString("ID"), resultSet.getString("FOOD_NAME"), resultSet.getString("QUANTITY"),
                        resultSet.getString("PRICE")));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        id_OrderListTableModel.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
        food_OrderListTableModel.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("foodName"));
        quantity_OrderListTableModel.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("qty"));
        price_OrderListTableModel.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));

        orderListTableModel.setItems(null);
        orderListTableModel.setItems(observableList);
    }
}
```

error code

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'null' at line 1
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3978)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3914)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2495)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1903)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2011)
    at sample.OrderListController.initialize(OrderListController.java:37)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2573)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at sample.MenuController.menuBtnClicked(MenuController.java:107)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1782)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3589)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8300(Scene.java:3517)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3885)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Scene.java:3604)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2613)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:189)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Btw this is my orderListTableModel

```
public class orderListTableModel {
    String id, foodName, qty, price;

    public orderListTableModel(String id, String foodName, String qty, String price) {
        this.id = id;
        this.foodName = foodName;
        this.qty = qty;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFoodName() {
        return foodName;
    }

    public void setFoodName(String foodName) {
        this.foodName = foodName;
    }

    public String getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(String qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't dynamically bind a table name in your query. At least, not without a stored procedure.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Hi, thanks for responding to my question. I haven't put a table name in my query. The variable is 'orderRefNo' which is generated in the previous scene and then transferred to the next scene controller from previous scene controller.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ?`. You are attempting to bind the table name in `FROM`. You cannot do that.

Comment: @ElliotFrisch Hi, orderRefNo is not a table name, it is a String variable passed into the controller

Comment: What do you think the line `preparedStatement.setString(1, orderRefNo);` is doing? I assure you, the reason it does not work is precisely because `orderRefNo` is being passed as a bind parameter where such is not permitted (**exactly** like when you did `"SELECT * FROM "+orderRefNo+""`) - you cannot bind a table name like that. I realize it "is a String variable passed into the controller", but you are trying to **use it like a table name**.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch ok, then is it possible to pass that string as a string to that sql statement.

Comment: I have told you three times; you **cannot do that**. You can write a stored procedure and use a callable statement to do something equivalent, but `PreparedStatement` is backed by a cursor; and database cursors are not generated in that manner (basically, there is no JDBC implementation that lets you do what you are trying to do with a `PreparedStatement`).

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot bind a table name to your SQL query using PreparedStatement**. PreparedStatement is for **column names**, not table names. I understand that orderRefNo references a String object, but you are still binding it as the table used in your`SELECT` statement when you construct your query.

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("**SELECT * FROM ?**");
preparedStatement.setString(1, orderRefNo);
```

Understand that you are using the String orderRefNo as a table name in your query, and this is not allowed. Therefore you get an Exception.

An alternative way you could pursue this is by concatenating the table name into your query, but you should **never do that** because it makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. I repeat, do not concatenate your table name directly into your query.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your clarification. Concatenation also don't work. In my concatenated statement above is commented out. But my problem is I was able to pass in a variable table name in an insert statement before in my program which worked fine.

Comment: `PreparedStatement preparedStatement1 = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO "+orderRefNo+" VALUES(null, 'Noodles6', '"+Pane4Item6Qty+"', '"+45*Pane4Item6Qty+"')");`
this worked fine

Comment: Can I know that how to create a stored procedure for this